# Failed Index rollover : Index management policy in AWS Opensearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards, index-management

I have an index management policy defined in my AWS Opensearch cluster to rollover indices when the index size >= 10GB. Below is the policy:

```
{
    "policy_id": "example_policy",
    "description": "Example policy",
    "last_updated_time": 1645709276389,
    "schema_version": 1,
    "error_notification": null,
    "default_state": "rollover",
    "states": [
        {
            "name": "rollover",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "rollover": {
                        "min_size": "10gb"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "transitions": []
        }
    ],
    "ism_template": [
        {
            "index_patterns": [
                "example-index*"
            ],
            "priority": 0,
            "last_updated_time": 1643722848235
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when the initial index example-index00001 size reached 10GB, the rollover happened and the data ingestion now happens to the rolled over index which is example-index00002 which is the expected behaviour.
But on the Index Management page in the Kibana dashboard, I get an error under "Policy Managed Indices" tab under the action info of the initial index. The below is the error I get

```
{
    "message": "Failed to find state= in policy=example_policy"
}
```

What am I missing here?
If I change the policy now (if required) then will that be automatically applied when the next rollover happens?

Thank you.

Comment: Change the default stat to 'hot' and then to rollover.